# The use of past perfect

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Is the following sentence correct? Or should I change the "had been moved" to "was moved", or should I change the "in 1980" to "by 1980"?

"Although the sports centre was situated close to the high school in 1950, in 1980 it had been moved closer to the hospital."

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct. You should use either:

> **in** 1980, it **was** moved

(the move happened *in* 1980)
or

> **by** 1980, it **had been** moved

(the move happened *sometime before* 1980).

The two sentences have different meanings, so you have to decide which one you actually want to use.